# HASHMAP syntax error in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

For some, my eclipse IDE complains whenever I do something like this:

`Map<Type,Type> map = new HashMap<Type,Type>();`

it underlines Map and prefers I do something like this:

`HashMap<Type,Type> map = new HashMap<Type,Type>();`

Same goes for all the other interfaces. What could be the problem with my eclipse?

Comment: What is the exact warning?

Comment: "underline" as in "warning", or as in "error"? Can you include a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

You have to `import java.util.Map`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's wrong with Eclipse (of course) assuming that you're using the Kepler release, but instead it's your settings that are off. You need to set your Java Compiler compliance setting to 1.7. It's currently set at less than that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you must set your JAVA compiler to 1.7. for reference see my below picutre.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read exact error message and suggestions.

Also check your current state of `HashMap`. Changing `Map` to `HashMap` is really an option, so Eclipse is correct.

The reason your Eclipse doesn't suggest to import `Map` is ambiguous.

Type all line and imports by hand and save all files. Then check what Eclipse will say.